# Finding drivers for Macbook Pro (13 inch, i5, 2.3GHZ) without bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, driver

I had a customer come in (regular) and brought me a mac his son screwed up by deleting partitions and installing windows. Somehow in the bootcamp process he screwed it all up.

So now there's a fresh windows 8 installation on it, but I cannot for the life of me find proper drivers for his wireless card and other items.

I have tried installing a driver for a different system (Acer system. Same chipset, same wireless card) but it failed in the setup (setup.rul 343)

Anyone know how to get this to work? The kid needs Windows for his distance schooling and has no mac disks to re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Get a Snow Leopard retail install disk. Fix the partitions and erase and install Snow Leopard. Download and install the latest SL combo update, or continue on the the usual upgrade path to Lion and/or Mountain Lion according to the customer's preference and the capabilities of the Mac.

Download and install VirtualBox. Make a new Windows VM and re-install Windows. Note that Bootcamp doesn't yet support Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

On this link you'll find direct downloads for the bootcamp drivers of all Mac models: http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.fr/p/model-identifiersize-driver-release.html